# Why are aspx files with <script> ignoring CompilerOptions directive containing version

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

I am manually specifying CompilerOptions in the aspx Page directive to point to an assemblyinfo.cs file so that the aspnet_compiler compiles the dll and sets the file version on the file per this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228042(v=vs.100).aspx

This works great on pages with no script tags in them, but if there is a script tag in the aspx page, the file version and product name is not set on the compiled file.

Looking at the aspnet_compiler cmdline output in Temporary ASPNET Files, I can see that if I include any  tags in the aspx page the commandline is:
...(bunch of refs).../out:{filehere} /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"{path}\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ _test\baa9b374\3a3079a4\55vmujzi.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 C:\MyFile\AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror-  {filename.0.cs} {filename.1.cs}

If I look at the aspnet_compiler output without the script in the aspx page, the /win32res parameter is not present and everything works great.

What magic step do I need to perform to get the aspnet_compiler to include the scripts AND use the proper assemblyinfo.cs information to set file version?

I am using the .NET 4 aspnet_compiler.

Comment: What do these script tags do? Are they `runat="server"`? Do they just have JavaScript code (functions) written in them? Or do they import / reference JavaScript files?

Comment: Here is an example:      <script type ="text/javascript">
        function testForEnterKeyPressed(obj, evt)
        {
            var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
            var objType = obj.type;
            if ((keyCode == 13) && (objType != "submit"))
            {
                evt.returnValue = false;
                if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    </script>

Comment: The other interesting thing is that if I comment out that script, it still fails.  I have to completely remove it from the master page (or aspx file) for the aspnet_compiler to give my generated dll a fileversion, copyright, etc.

Comment: That's bizarre.  I'm not sure what else to do.